# Specflow hooks can access the test data for backend?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bdd, specflow

It is a web based application having 100 respondents each respondent have different ids. i have to run my test cases for all respondents using id which are listed in test data file. file consists of 100 respondent ids, using this file i have to select an id in backend and run the application. here i have to choose the id before the application launched. so, in this case can we use Before feature hook to access that file to select option in backend. is it possible for specflow hooks to access the data from file

If this processes not work then help me is there another way to get test data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please explain the business behavior you are trying to verify? I do understand you are trying to get some support to help with your implementation but without understanding what business behavior you are trying to test, it would be difficult to provide the right solution

Comment: Hi Jerome, it is a web based application having 100 respondents each respondent have different ids. i have to run my test cases for all respondents using id which are listed in test data file. file consists of 100 respondent ids, using this file i have to select an id in backend and run the application. here i have to choose the id before the application launched. so, in this case can we use Before feature hook to access that file to select option in backend. is it possible for specflow hooks to access the data from file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: I just want to know is it possible to do with specflow hooks if not i have to change the procedure of database. thats why trying to the solution of it.sorry if did anything wrong?

Comment: Hi everyone, please provide the answer for the below one:
it is a web based application having 100 respondents each respondent have different ids. i have to run my test cases for all respondents using id which are listed in test data file. file consists of 100 respondent ids, using this file i have to select an id in backend and run the application. here i have to choose the id before the application launched. so, in this case can we use Before feature hook to access that file to select option in backend. is it possible for specflow hooks to access the data from file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I need to update the database for my test data. I have used the BeforeScenario hook to execute. But I ran into a problem that I do not have to do for each test case.
The alternative was to use tag and scope in BeforeScenario.

Or use Background
*Feature: LoginFeature
Background:
Given Test Data is updated in Db
Scenario: First Scenario*

In my case Background worked best.

Comment: Hi Navin, In this case you have used any external data files to update the data base in scenario hooks or used the data from feature file. here i have to use external data file to for services id

Comment: Hi @Trt - How do you get id from the external service? Is that via API or a SQL query?